# Internal WiFi card not working on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.10, realtek-wireless

I have an HP Notebook 15-rb001ne laptop with Realtek RTL8723BE internal WiFi card and I have installed Ubuntu 18.10 on the laptop and I can say that everything looks good and the system is working smoothly except one thing, the internal WiFi card.

When I go to Settings, there is no WiFi menu even if the aireplane mode is disabled, but when I type `sudo lspci -v` command in the terminal and press Enter, the internal WiFi card is listed with all its details and features and when typing uname -r, the kernel version is 4.18.0-12 generic.

How can I install the correct driver to get the WiFi card working?

How can I fix this problem without having to buy an external WiFi card?

Comment: The wifi widget/locater for the Gnome-Network-Manager and WPA capabilities  are both in /usr/share/ applications I believe and they're directed to /sbin/wpasupplicant, I can be more precise when I get home in 7 hours if you don't get a reply before then

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be && dmesg | grep rtl`